# How do I use multiple navbars in my react application

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to have a **different navbar** for each path in my website, i figured out a way but it doesn't really change **until I refresh the page** which is obviously not what i want. ( I'm using react router v6.**3** )

```
    function Navbar() {
if (window.location.pathname === "/") {
return (
<nav style={{ backgroundColor: "rgb(17, 105, 142)" }}>...</nav>
);
} else if (window.location.pathname === "/products") {
return (
<nav className="products-nav">...</nav>
);
} else if (window.location.pathname === "/addproducts") {
return (
<nav className="addproducts-nav">...</nav>
);
} else ...
```

[Here](https://ibb.co/9TcnsDf)'s the full code just in case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use useLocation hook from react-router-dom which returns the current location object https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location

```js
import React from 'react'
import useLocatio from 'react-router-dom'

const functionalComponent = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    console.log(location.pathname)
    return ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react router you shouldn't be using `window.location` directly anymore. Use the values available from react router. `window.location` changes won't trigger a re-render which is why you aren't seeing your changes.

The react router equivalent would be to use the [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location) hook

Comment: What props exactly?

Comment: The location is available from react-router's context with the useLocation hook

Comment: The other option would be to render the navbar as a child of each route you define instead of switching based on the location value.

Comment: I thought about something like that but i wanted to leave it as the last way to do it, i'll look into the useLocation hook